# How do I emulate a map click in Leaflet on a geoJson layer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

The map click is useful as it helps me avoid solving a nasty Point In Polygon problem, but my code does not appear to be correctly triggering clicks when the simulateClick() function is called. Here's what I've got:

```
simulateClick = function(lat, lng) {
    var latlngPoint = new L.LatLng(parseInt(lat), parseInt(lng));
    map.fireEvent('click', {
        latlng: latlngPoint,
        layerPoint: map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlngPoint),
        containerPoint: map.latLngToContainerPOint(latlngPoint)
    });
};
```

It does not trigger the click event I've tied to the geoJson items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
new L.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
```

But really it's not [actually hard to do point in polygon in leaflet with a simple library](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) and, unlike this approach, it'll work with features that are outside your current viewport.